# python repr() function doesnt return \"

Tags: python, json

Im getting json-like string from server. It has `\"` instead of normal `"` char. When Im converting it with `json.loads()` it gives error.

```
> import json
> from_page = '{"data": "There is start: \"Hello there!\". There is end."}'
> from_page
'{"data": "There is start: "Hello there!". There is end."}'
> json.loads(from_page)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 28 (char 27)
```

When I put `\\"` instead of `\"` it works fine.

```
> from_page = '{"data": "There is start: \\"Hello there!\\". There is end."}'
> from_page
'{"data": "There is start: \\"Hello there!\\". There is end."}'
> json.loads(from_page)
{'data': 'There is start: "Hello there!". There is end.'}
```

But problem is that I cant access data from page directly, so I cant use `r""`. I wanted to use `repr()` and then convert `\` to `\\` but `repr()` function shows `"` instead of `\"`, so I cant do anything with that.

```
> from_page = '{"data": "There is start: \"Hello there!\". There is end."}'
> from_page
'{"data": "There is start: "Hello there!". There is end."}'
> repr(from_page)
'\'{"data": "There is start: "Hello there!". There is end."}\''
```

What would be the most efficient way to deal with this?

Comment: Why do you need to use repr() at all?

Comment: I am trying to replace \ with \\

Comment: The string `'\"'` has only one character: a double quote. There are no backslashes in that string. Make sure your data source is actually proper json, and not just that you've copy-pasted as a python literal string.

Comment: @Dennis: It's not a legal Python literal either, if `repr` shows no backslashes on those quotes. I have no idea why they think the backslashes are there at all when they're clearly not. My guess is the raw data the server sends might have backslashes in it, but they're parsing it in some way that's not just a raw read of the raw bytes, and the backslashes get evaluated in some way that eliminates them. But if it's happening, it's either unrelated to Python string literals, or they themselves are applying such a transform to interpret them as such, e.g. with `eval`/`ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't declare your `from_page` variable like that, because escaped quotation mark in a regular string is just a quotation mark:

```
>>> var = '\"'
>>> len(var)
1
```

There is only one character in the `var` variable - the quotation mark. No backslash to convert to double backslash. So when you declare your `from_page`, it's content is just like displayed (note the quotation marks):

```
'{"data": "There is start: "Hello there!". There is end."}'
  ^----^  ^----------------^            ^---------------^
```

You need to declare your string as 'raw', adding an 'r' character in front of it:

```
>>> from_page = r'{"data": "There is start: \"Hello there!\". There is end."}'
>> from_page
'{"data": "There is start: \\"Hello there!\\". There is end."}'
>>> json.loads(from_page)
{'data': 'There is start: "Hello there!". There is end.'}
```

Comment: Yeah, mb. I was thinking ahead too much and wanted to simulate getting data from page assuming its not raw.